# Static Assets in Django not Finding STATICFILES_DIRS

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

Here is the error I receive when trying to load {{STATIC_URL}}img/memestatlogo2.jpg.  Why is django not looking in STATICFILES_DIRS for img/memestatlogo2.jpg?

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/img/memestatlogo2.jpg

Using the URLconf defined in memestat.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
^$
The current URL, static/img/memestatlogo2.jpg, didn't match any of these.
```

Here are relevant configurations form my settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/memestat/stats/')
```

The image is then located in

'/home/ryan/Programming/OpenCV-2.4.2/msheroku/memestat/stats/img/memestatlogo2.jpg'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`STATICFILES_DIRS` is only used when you execute the `collectstatic` command. Files are then copied into `STATIC_ROOT` which in the example above is unset.

You need to set `STATIC_ROOT` to a dir where you want your static files to be copied. This dir also holds your project-wide static files that are not part of any app like perhaps robots.txt, favicon.ico, your logo(s) and background images.

Comment: How should I load static assets without STATICFILES_DIRS?

Comment: The built-in debug server (runserver command) will serve files from STATIC_ROOT if debug=True. That is all there is to it.

Comment: You can use collectstatic to copy files to STATIC_ROOT. By default collectstatic looks for files in two locations:
1. the /static/ dir in each installed app and
2. each dir listed in STATICFILES_DIRS

Comment: How do I run collectstatic?  python manage.py collectstatic gives me an error and it doesn't seem to be an option when I look under help.

Comment: I changed STATIC_ROOT and put the relevant image there, still no dice

Comment: What version of Django are you using and do you have django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS?

Comment: >>> django.VERSION
(1, 4, 3, 'final', 0)
.I uncommented out django.contrib.staticfiles in INSTALLED_APPS.  Same result.

Comment: I upgraded my version of django and everything's running smoothly now.